# MySQL with PHP book

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a proficient programmer, and I can write PHP code without any trouble, but, I run away from MySQL, in my own projects, I use the excellent RedBean object mapper, but, for freelance projects, I have to learn MySQL, and its calls from PHP, what books what you guys recommend?

It would be great if the book suggested is available on [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/)

Comment: Why don't you use RedBean as well for your own projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Luke Welling's *[PHP and MySQL Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)* to have a good overview of the MySql functions in PHP. The aforementioned *Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript* is excellent as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596157135/) to be helpful, but it sounds like you are well beyond that. In that case take a look at [Web Database Applications with PHP and MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005436/). Both are from O'Reilly.

Comment: I am unable to get this book for a reasonable price in my area (India), do you have any good alternatives? (I'm talking about the second book)

Answer (score 0):

And once you get familiarized with basic MySQL queries, you might be excited to jump ahead and learn about some performance reading: [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718) and [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) offer a lot of knowledge. Freelance projects that become popular often need database tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Basic things you can read in [Zend PHP5 Certification Study Guide](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-zend-php-5-certification-study-guide-2nd-edition/).
And for more advanced usage [Expert PHP and MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470563125)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's better than the PHP and MySQL documentation.

I will recommend referring the PHP manual to learn how to connect to MySQL and execute queries and read results from PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

The MySQL manual itself very efficiently explains the subject - its mainly the following query types that you'll be mostly looking for:

CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
INSERT
SELECT
UPDATE
DELETE

Refer to chapters 10, 11 and 12 to get started - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/.